# parse directly on pure html source with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I'm trying to test the selenium program that I wrote by giving it an HTML source as a string for some reasons such as speed. I don't want it to get the URL and I don't want it to open a file I just want to pass it a string that contains whole DIV part of that site and do parsing stuff on it.
this is part of a module that i wrote:

```
source = driver.page_source
return {'containers': source}
```

and in another module,

```
def get_rail_origin(self):
    return self.data['containers'].find_element_by_id('o_outDepName')...
```

I'm trying to do parsing stuff on it but I get

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'

So how can I parse on pure HTML source without opening any file or URL

Answer (score 1):

Selenium works with *live* HTML DOM. If you want to get source and then parse it, you can try, for instance, [`lxml.html`](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html):

```
def get_rail_origin(self):
    source = html.fromstring(self.data['containers'])
    return source.get_element_by_id('o_outDepName')
```

P.S. I assumed that `self.data['containers']` is HTML source code

Comment: yes self.data['containers'] is html source. AttributeError: 'HtmlElement' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id' i get this error

Comment: @iman_sh77 , where you get that `find_element_by_id` from? I used `get_element_by_id` in my code!

Comment: I have a bunch of these find_element_by_id and find_elements_by_xpath. and that function was one of them like this: self.data['containers'].find_element_by_id('st_statusNm').text

Comment: @iman_sh77 `find_elements_by_xpath` and `find_element_by_id` are Selenium methods. In lxml you should use `xpath` and `get_element_by_id` instead

Comment: so you mean I can't do parsing from HTML source (offline) with selenium and instead, I should use sth like bs4?

Comment: @iman_sh77 , yes, exactly. Selenium is a tool that allows to interact with browser and a DOM while you need a tool to parse HTML code...

Comment: but i did such thing with selenium : event = [self.data['containers'].execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', cell).strip() for cell in event_path] i should migrate codes to bs4?

Comment: @iman_sh77 , hmm... That's interesting. But note that `execute_script` is method-container that just allows to inject JavaScript passed as argument. If it works for you you can execute every required operation as JavaScript

Comment: things got complicated! till now I used selenium to do some interaction with browser and pull out datas that I want from it. But now I need to pass source (not in file or URL) and pull out same datas the only diffrence is the source part.Guess I should migrate the parsing part completly to bs4 or scrapy :( right?

Comment: @iman_sh77 If your goal is to scrape some data from web then you don't need Selenium at all! I prefer to use `python-requests` + `lxml.html`

Comment: unfortunately, I must enter some input at first so using selenium is a must. till now I have the job done but the employer needs test cases passing the source and check if my codes result is correct because of that if selenium can't handle pure source I should do automated part with selenium and get data and pass it to bs4 right?

Comment: @iman_sh77 , not exactly. Even if you need to fill some forms and click some buttons it's all can be done via direct HTTP request (you might need to pass some parameters to your request). But if your goal is to test web-UI, then you should do this with Selenium

Comment: in that webpage, the content is behind the ajax and its secured and I tried to access with json and stuff but it was not possible.so it's not straightforward to access via direct HTTP request, even its possible I guess sticking to selenium is more wisely cuz I wrote it already and it takes time to migrate(it's my opinion but if you think it worth doing I'll do so)

Comment: @iman_sh77 , it's hard to tell how to solve the issue best as I don't know how exactly that page behaves